# AtomicInteger a1 increase before a2, and decrease after a2, why exists a2 > a1

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, atomic

there is the code:

```java
        AtomicInteger a1 = new AtomicInteger();
        AtomicInteger a2 = new AtomicInteger();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            new Thread(()->{
                for (int j = 0; j < 1e4; j++) {
                    a1.incrementAndGet();
                    a2.incrementAndGet();
                    int v2 = a2.decrementAndGet();
                    if(v2>a1.get()){
                        System.out.println("error a2 > a1");
                    }
                    a1.decrementAndGet();
                }
            }).start();
        }
```

why exists println `error a2 > a1`?

thanks!

| action | a1 | a2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1+ | 1 | 0 |
| a2+ | 1 | 1 |
| a2- | 1 | 0 |
| a1- | 0 | 0 |

use `redhat windows openjdk-1.8.0.222`

Comment: Multiple threads can execute that code simultaniously. This could lead to `v2` getting incremented between `a2.decrementAndGet()` and `a1.get()`.

Comment: To expand on @dan1st's comment: if we move the declaration of variables `a1` and `a2` into the lambda, the behaviour should be as expected. Likewise, the behaviour should be as expected if we `synchronized(a1) { ... }` or `synchronized(a2) { ... }` the body of the inner `for`-loop. The behaviour should also be as expected, if we only start one thread that executes the lambda.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Imagine this scenario**:

All 100 threads complete the increments and the last thread now has `a1 = 100, a2 = 100`.

Now the first thread to calculate v2 will get `v2 = 99`.

If the other 99 threads finish and decrement before that one thread goes any further, it will then be checking `99 > 1` and be true.

**Short answer**: Other threads can decrement `a1` between `int v2 = a2.decrementAndGet()` and `if(v2>a1.get())`

Comment: And the great lesson to take from this: just because each action you take is atomic does **not** mean that your whole unit of work is atomic!

Comment: @JoachimSauer yes, and the other lesson is, threads executing the same code are not coupled. They are not required to do the same thing at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by jdkramhoft](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67853210/642706) is correct. You have two resources (the pair of `AtomicInteger` objects) being manipulated across threads that are not protected. Each *individual* call to increment, decrement, and get on each `AtomicInteger` happens atomically. But multiple calls across threads may be interleaved, not atomic, not thread-safe.

To make the group of increment, decrement, and get calls atomic, you must guard them as a group. One easy way to do that is to use `synchronized`. In the code below we arbitrarily chose our `AtomicInteger` named `a1` to be the lock object for our `synchronized` call.

By synchronizing the code block on the same object (`a1`), we guarantee that only one thread at a time may be running that code block. When the other thread gets to the point of trying to run that block, it must wait for the `synchronized` lock to be freed.

The use of `1e4` is a bit precious, so let's use `10_000` instead. Even `1_000` is enough for our purposes here, and is less likely to [blow out our console buffer](https://www.andreadelis.com/increase-console-output-size-in-intellij-idea/).

I am no expert on concurrency, but the following code seems thread-safe to me. Perhaps others can point out any flaws. At any rate, use at your own risk.

```java
package work.basil.demo.threads;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - Starting the main method of our demo. " + Instant.now() );
        AtomicInteger a1 = new AtomicInteger();
        AtomicInteger a2 = new AtomicInteger();
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println( "Instantiating thread # " + i + "  |  " + Instant.now() );
            new Thread( ( ) -> {
                for ( int j = 0 ; j < 1_000 ; j++ )
                {
                    synchronized ( a1 )
                    {
                        a1.incrementAndGet();
                        a2.incrementAndGet();
                        int v2 = a2.decrementAndGet();
                        if ( v2 > a1.get() )
                        {
                            System.out.println( "error a2 > a1" );
                        }
                        a1.decrementAndGet();
                    }
                    System.out.println( "Finishing thread id " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " | " + Instant.now() );
                }
            } ).start();
        }
        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 10 ).toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        System.out.println( "a1 = " + a1.get() );
        System.out.println( "a2 = " + a2.get() );
    }
}
```

When run.

```
INFO - Starting the main method of our demo. 2021-06-06T00:05:12.869874Z
Instantiating thread # 0  |  2021-06-06T00:05:12.875289Z
Instantiating thread # 1  |  2021-06-06T00:05:12.887569Z
Instantiating thread # 2  |  2021-06-06T00:05:12.888805Z
Instantiating thread # 3  |  2021-06-06T00:05:12.891298Z
Finishing thread id 16 | 2021-06-06T00:05:12.891789Z
Finishing thread id 16 | 2021-06-06T00:05:12.894783Z
…
Finishing thread id 57 | 2021-06-06T00:05:13.634241Z
Finishing thread id 57 | 2021-06-06T00:05:13.634245Z
Finishing thread id 57 | 2021-06-06T00:05:13.634247Z
a1 = 0
a2 = 0
```

---

By the way, a quick mention: In modern Java, we rarely need to address the `Thread` class directly. Better to use the Executors framework added to Java 5. Submit your tasks as `Runnable`/`Callable` object to be run on background threads.

Comment: thanks, the mention is useful, I like it.

Comment: Even though I am not fully sure, In the above, the major code of the thread is synchronized (omitting sysout). Doesn't that make usage of thread in the above code unnecessary? Because effectively only one thread would be executing at a time. Only the loop counter increment could happen concurrently right?

Comment: @GauthamM Yes, indeed. If in a real app the entire workload of the task were contained within a synchronized block, then there may not be any point to having more than one background thread, you could just as well submit all the tasks to a single-threaded executor service. …

Comment: … However, that is not quite the case here. Notice that we have a `j` loop outside our synchronized block. So in our case both threads are making progress through their respective loops, though never simultaneously, but occasionally switching back and forth. Imagine long tasks like processing big files, with some incremental progress being made over time, each thread reporting chunks of their results as they grind away at their workload.